# Stable \(\textcircled{r}\}?

Tags: symbols

In part of a text I want to use `\(\textcircled{r}\)` for *or* in the metalanguage, much as `\(\&\)` is used for *conjunction* in the metalanguage. I do not want to use `\(\textregistered\)` or `\(\faRegistered\)`, as that could come across as dishonest.

The problem is that the encircled *r* is unstable, so that it does not always occur in the center of the circle. Is there a way to ensure stability?

Comment: You can try `circledtext`.

Comment: Can you please show your attempt?

Comment: @egreg Yes, after I have read up on robust commands...

Comment: @egreg \DeclareRobustCommand{\jim}{\textcircled{r}}

Comment: @egreg It was an attempt, but not satisfactory in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to use it in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\metaand}{\mathbin{\&}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\metaor}{\mathbin{\text{\textcircled{r}}}}

\begin{document}

$A\metaor B^{C\metaor D^{E\metaor F}}$

$A\metaand B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yes, the circle becomes oval in superscripts or subscripts. If you don't use it there, just ignore the issue. Otherwise you want to scale down the text style symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\metaand}{\mathbin{\&}}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\metaor}{\mathbin{\metaor@}}
\newcommand{\metaor@}{%
  \mathchoice{\metaor@@{\f@size}}{\metaor@@{\f@size}}
             {\metaor@@{\sf@size}}{\metaor@@{\ssf@size}}%
}
\newcommand{\metaor@@}[1]{\scalebox{\fpeval{(#1)/(\f@size)}}{\textcircled{r}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\metaor B^{C\metaor D^{E\metaor F}}$

$A\metaand B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I think I will try to employ the second solution.